# In Android Studio What's use of "Layout Captures" tool

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

**"Layout Captures"** tool in Android Studio showing nothing to show , how can i use this tool ?

and what's use of that ?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Layout Captures" shows you all layout that were captured by the "Layout Inspector." Yours is empty since you have not captured any layouts. See [Layout Inspector documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector).

To see how this works, capture a layout from a running emulator or attached device using the Layout Inspector which is invoked from the menu:

[image]

Here is an example of a layout that was captured. Various aspects of the layout can be inspected from this screen and can be very useful when debugging a layout.

[image]

You can now see this layout in "Layout Captures." All captures will be displayed in this tab so you can refer to them. You can also delete old layout capture files from this screen.

[image]